# Deleting all messages from somebody on Discord

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a bot that will delete all messages from another bot. A bot malfunctioned and spammed a whole bunch of messages, and so I want to delete the messages, which would take absurdly long.

Comment: OK, so what exactly do you need help with? It sounds like you've already written a successful bot, so you've got the basics of connecting to discord: I guess the next steps are to find the other bot user, search for all messages for them (globally in the server, or channel by channel iterating through the channel list?) and then call delete on each message? Which bit do you need help with?

Comment: I need help writing a command to delete the messages from a certain user. Would it be something like    message.delete.all(from{@user})

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 12.2.0

Comment: I think the best API you've got is [TextChannel.bulkDelete](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=bulkDelete), which looks like it wants to be given a list of message IDs not a simple 'from user' filter. But I may be wrong, I don't know discord-js well.

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch all messages from the channel. Then filter it by userID and delete

In your post you said that your bot spammed the messages so this code is for removing your bot's messages

```js
message.channel.messages.fetch().then(messages => {
    const botMessages = messages.filter(msg => msg.author.bot);
    message.channel.bulkDelete(botMessages);
})
```